# Parsing data then appending a header

Tags: c#

In my Class, I'm taking data that is delimited into 19 different strings, then I'm trying to add the headers shown at the bottom in front of the parsed data.

I'm getting an overflow - what am I doing wrong?

```
public class Call
{
    public Call(string ParsedData)
    {
        ParseData(ParsedData);
    }


    private void ParseData(string ParsedData)
    {
       string[] stringSeparators = new string[] { "," };
       string[] items = ParsedData.Split(stringSeparators, StringSplitOptions.None);

       try
       {
           using (System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\Public\TestFolder\Writetext1.txt", true))
           {

               List<Call> CallList = new List<Call>();
               foreach (string s in items)
               {
                   Console.WriteLine(s);

                   Call c = new Call(s);
                   CallList.Add(c);

                   file.WriteLine(c);
               }
           }
       }

       catch (Exception e)
       {
           Console.WriteLine("{0} Exception caught.", e);
       }

       CallID = items[0];
       Num2 = items[1];
       UTCStart = items[2];
       CallLengthSeconds = items[3];
       FromPort = items[4];
       FromDescription = items[5];
       FromCIDName = items[6];
       FromCIDNumber = items[7];
       ToPort = items[8];
       ToDescription = items[9];
       ToCIDName = items[10];
       ToCIDNumber = items[11];
       Num14 = items[12];
       Digits = items[13];
       TC = items[14];
       Num17 = items[15];
       FromDNISName = items[16];
       FromDNISNumber = items[17];
       CallConnected = items[18];
       //etc
   }
   public string CallID { get; set; }
   public string Num2 { get; set; }
   public string UTCStart { get; set; }
   public string CallLengthSeconds { get; set; }
   public string FromPort { get; set; }
   public string FromDescription { get; set; }
   public string FromCIDName { get; set; }
   public string FromCIDNumber { get; set; }
   public string ToPort { get; set; }
   public string ToDescription { get; set; }
   public string ToCIDName { get; set; }
   public string ToCIDNumber { get; set; }
   public string Num14 { get; set; }
   public string Digits { get; set; }
   public string TC { get; set; }
   public string Num17 { get; set; }
   public string FromDNISName { get; set; }
   public string FromDNISNumber { get; set; }
   public string CallConnected { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Overflow of what? Please post the exception.

Comment: @Caramiriel I bet for a stackoverflow.

Comment: yeah, the endless loop because it was calling to itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
Call c = new Call(s);
```

calls

```
public Call(string ParsedData)
{
    ParseData(ParsedData);
}
```

which call

```
private void ParseData(string ParsedData)
```

In which you find:

```
Call c = new Call(s);
```

See...?

Comment: Thank you, I actually vetted the whole call<list> I realize that i should have been calling it from another call. most likely my parser. I ended up using a .zip to append the data that i wanted.

Comment: @rem0nster next time don't hesitate to use the VS debugger, it would have helped you to spot the issue :)

Comment: Thank you, I'm doing my internship right now and they want me to create a phone system software. it's a nightmare but it's going alright.